# SQL Server database Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have two tables `tbl_evidence` and `tbl_test_result`.

I want `eve_id` as column by using pivot. But the problem is I need only distinct id but the table is creating multiple rows for same id and putting null value for other column.

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   
    @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(eve_id)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT eve_id 
     FROM [dbo].[tbl_evidence] 
     WHERE cls_id=13) AS evidence

SELECT @PivotColumns

SET @SQLQuery =  'SELECT reg_id, '+   @PivotColumns + 'FROM tbl_evidence join tbl_test_result on tbl_evidence.eve_id= tbl_test_result.test_id 
    PIVOT( max(test_marks) FOR eve_id IN (' + @PivotColumns +')) AS P where cls_id=13 order by reg_id'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

[![The result i am getting now with null values][1]][1]

```
reg_id  6   13  14  27   33    37    45   48    50
----------------------------------------------------
979    NULL NULL 9  NULL NULL  NULL  NULL NULL  NULL
```

I want result like

```
reg_id  6   13  14  27  33  37  45  48  50
--------------------------------------------    
979     18  18  9   16  6   36  18  15  0
```

Comment: It would probably help if you provided data, right?

Comment: I once wrote a SQL CLR function for creating a dynamic pivot.  Not sure if it will help you but you can try it out. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/.Net/94922/